# Why can't Apache2 look outside /var/www/html/ for a PHP file?

Tags: 16.04, permissions, apache2, php

I have just started to learn about the whole deal of PHP, MySql, and it's connections to front-end development. While doing this I found that I cannot execute a PHP file unless and until it is inside the /var/www/html directory. I have found out about this solution from multiple sources including askubuntu, but I could never find the reason as to why this is so. So does this mean that a PHP file always has to be inside this specific directory? Can I do anything to make a PHP file inside say, my Documents folder to run successfully instead of being "Save"-ad by Mozilla?
Please help.

Comment: I'm not an expert on the issue, but apache will NEVER look outside of the document root, which is specified in the config files.

Comment: "but I could never find the reason as to why this is so".  S e c u r i t y.

Comment: There's only one config file you need to change. There's a great tutorial video here: https://youtu.be/rNAGlpEod0Y?t=11

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it is not configured to do so, by default Apache will only serve php file inside `/var/www/html` directory.

You can set Apache to look content anywhere within your system, in order to achieve such thing you need to change Apache setting, they are mostly located on `/etc/apache2`.

> **Please note, that this only applies for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and newer releases.**
>
> In my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, the document root was set to `/var/www/html`.
>   It was configured in the following file:
>
> ```
> /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
> ```
>
> So just do a
>
> ```
> sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
> ```
>
> and change the following line to what you want:
>
> ```
> DocumentRoot /var/www/html
> ```
>
> Also do a
>
> ```
> sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
> ```
>
> and find this
>
> ```
> <Directory /var/www/html/>    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks  AllowOverride None  Require all granted
> </Directory>
> ```
>
> and change `/var/www/html` to your preferred directory
>
> and save it.
>
> After you saved your changes, just restart the apache2 webserver and
>   you'll be done :)
>
> ```
> sudo service apache2 restart
> ```
>
> ---
>
> If you prefer a graphical text editor, you can just replace the `sudo nano` by a `gksu gedit`.

<sub>Taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23175981</sub>

Comment: It does not answer the "but I could never find the reason as to why this is so"

Answer (score 1):

The reason php files not possible to open outside of document root is **security**. Web server always limited to some folder and its subfolders.

You can setup apache to look at few different folders, depending on url, like `http://localhost` or `http://someother.localhost` pointing to different folders.
To do so, first you need to edit 000-defailt.conf, the change is:

```
ServerName  localhost
ServerAlias localhost
```

Then make copy of 000-default.conf to 001-someother.conf and edit it like following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/leonid/Web/SomeotherRoot
    ServerName  someother.localhost
    ServerAlias someother.localhost
    <Directory "/home/leonid/Web/SomeotherRoot">
      AllowOverride All
      Require local
      # ^ this will limit connections to only local
    </Directory>
    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    LogLevel error
</VirtualHost>
```

After that you need to make someother.localhost resolve to server ip, edit /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost   *.localhost
...other lines
```

Finally you need to enable new configuration file by:

```
sudo a2ensite 001-someother.conf
sudo systemctl reload apache2
```

Note: Example above is only for local site, accessible only locally.
I wrote script what creates configurations like this in a few clicks, but better to understood how its done before using script. [Github](https://github.com/LeonidMew/CreateVirtualHost).

Comment: @Rinzwind Good point, I thought its not necessary with explanation how it working. Updated answer.

Comment: +1 from me. Security is almost always the answer to how apache is set up ;)